# Use an ellipsis to trigger a Pop Up Menu of hidden page links on-click

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, storybook, breadcrumbs

We are having these 3 props in the breadcrumb; if the number of items in the breadcrumb increases, then it deviates to use an ellipsis.

*itemsAfterCollapse* =>If the maximum number of items is exceeded, the number of items will show after the ellipsis.

*itemsBeforeCollapse*=>If the maximum number of items is exceeded, the number of items will show before the ellipsis.

*maxItems*=> Specifies the maximum number of breadcrumbs to display. When there are more than the maximum number, only the first itemsBeforeCollapse and last itemsAfterCollapse will be shown, with an ellipsis in between.

*Is it possible to build the above feature into the built-in breadcrumb component, where each slot is chip mui ? In developer tools, I have observed it. The combination of lists includes this ellipse svg, how can we use to built below feature.*

[image]

```
const Breadcrumbs = ({ links }) => {


  const renderBreadcrumbLinks = () => {
    return links.map((link, index) => {
      const { label, href} = link;
       
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={key}>
          <Chip
            component="a"
            href={href}
            label={label}
            onDelete={handleDelete}
            deleteIcon={deleteIcon}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    });
  };

  return <Breadcrumbs  component={Paper} itemsAfterCollapse={2} itemsBeforeCollapse={1} maxItems={4} elevation={0}>{renderBreadcrumbLinks()}</CMUI>;
};

export default Breadcrumbs;
```